# XCode 13.4.1 - SwiftUI iPhone simulator does not display content (white screen)

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-simulator, xcode13

As the heading states, I do not get the contents on my live preview appearing on the simulator. The issue does not seem to stem from a syntax error, as the simulator runs perfectly fine. Current solutions I have found have been completed using the storyboard, not the swiftUI.

I have only been able to "resolve" the error through a painstaking restart on my computer every time I update the code. Any solutions appreciated.

[image: example]

Update 1: The white screen persists across projects as well. It may be a software problem, so I am considering reinstalling XCode.

Update 2: "Hello World" works after a bit of waiting. It seems to simply be a really slow launch time..

Answer (score 0):

I realised that all I had to do was run the simulator and then stop the simulator. Then, the updated form would appear within the app.